# Flutter sending integer values from one page to another

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a location based app and in the settings page I have an option the allows users to change their location radius using the slider package. Such that when the slider is moved, more or less content gets shown in the home screen.

I tried sending the data using setstate but it seems not to be working for integer values

Am encountering the following problems

1.When the slider is moved, the changes dont reflect on the home page, I know this since ive inserted a text widget in the home screen to display  the slider value.

2.On the settings page where the slider is, whenever I slide it, it updates but when I navigate to another screen then back to the settings screen, the slider resets to the minimum value.
How can I solve the above problems?

**Here is my slider code on the settings page**

```
Slider(
            value: radius,
            onChanged: (newRadius) async{
              setState(() {
                tasks = newRadius.toDouble();
                String step2 = radius.toStringAsFixed(2);
                twodecimalradius = double.parse(step2); //converting the slider value to 2 decimal places

              });
              print(twodecimalradius);
              await Home(twodecimalradius:twodecimalradius); //passing the slider value to homepage
              await Home.staticGlobalKey.currentState.getposts();//a function in the homepage that gets called whenever the slider value is changed
            },

            min: 10.0,
            max: 500.0,
            //activeColor: Colors.red[400],
          )
```

**And in my homepage this is the code that is supposed to display the slider value in a text widget**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  
  var twodecimalradius;

  static final GlobalKey<_HomeState> staticGlobalKey =
  new GlobalKey<_HomeState>();

  Home({
    
    this.twodecimalradius,

  }): super(key: Home.staticGlobalKey);


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(body:Text(widget.twodecimalradius))
}
```

Comment: When you navigating to other screen you can set your slider’s min value to your sliders value

Comment: Check the Simple app state management tutorial at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple, this will show you how to pass the value between the screens. Also the value will be stored in the provider class, so it will resolve the second issue with reset the slider on the settings page.